# insetBy returns Inf in CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, geometry, core-graphics

I am using `insetBy` of `CGGeometry`, but it returns `inf` as value for `x` and `y`.

**CGGeometry**

```
public func insetBy(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat) -> CGRect
```

Below is my code with output :

```
    let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[row], y: yOffset[row], width: width, height: height)
    print(frame)     //(0.0, 0.0, 54.0, -3.0)

    let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: 4.0, dy: 2.0)
    print(insetFrame)   //(inf, inf, 0.0, 0.0)
```

This frame cause crash in application.
Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by negative height? :)

Comment: My mistake to catch that, as height calculation is dynamic and depend on other variables.So miss the catch. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative `width`/`height` doesn't make sense and it obviously breaks the CGRect calculations.

Just don't use negative values for `width` and `height` and you'll be fine:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[row], y: yOffset[row], width: max(8, width), height: max(4, height))
```

You can define some `maxInsetX` and `maxInsetY` constant, to be sure that your initial frames will never be smaller than `2*maxInset` in both dimensions.

Comment: Actually height value was passing negative. Thanks

Comment: @technerd In fact passing 0 will not solve the problem if you inset that dimension with a positive value afterwards. See the updated answer